# Tensorflow input shape explanation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

So I have multiple images in an array. The shape of one image is (28,28,1). When I now train my model like this :

```
model.fit(X,Y, epochs = 100, batch_size = 15, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

I get an input shape of (1,28,28,1). Where is the extra dimension coming from? Also the output shape of the final model is (1,1), although my last shape looks like this:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```

As I understand tensorflow the input shape should be (28,28,1) and the output shape should be (1). Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The additional dimension is related to the batch. In fact, all the data (tensors) handled by keras must come with the first axis specifying the position of each element in the respective batch. Consider that this behavior is enforced automatically by keras, so you never need to specify the batch dimension explicitly (for instance, in the Input layer when you use the functional API), but it is always there.

It is not clear what your X and Y variables are exactly, but what you get is basically saying that your input is a batch of size 1 composed of elements of shape (28, 28, 1), while the output is a batch of size 1 (of course, the batch sizes must match) with every element of shape (1,). This is correct since 1 is the number of outputs you provided for the Dense layer.

I hope I've been clear enough. Let me know if you need further help!

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Do you have any lecture or reference about it. I need to write a paper about it and need references about it.

Comment: @KarlWolf the official keras introduction on the Tensorflow site may be a good starting point [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model). The best reference I could give you anyway is the book _Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow_ by Aurelien Geron, it has everything you'd like to know for starting and beyond.